# Grails Searchable plugin and GORM marshalling

Tags: grails, grails-orm, searchable, grails-searchable, searchable-plugin

I have an one-to-one relationship (hasOne in User domain and belongsTo in UserInfo domain). When the BootStrap is executing I get an exception:

> org.compass.core.converter.ConversionException: Trying to marshall a null id [id] for alias [UserInfo]

this line of code produces it:

```
def user = new User(....., new UserInfo()).save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Peter Ledbrook, this is a non-trivial conflict between Hibernate and Searchable: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSEARCHABLE-19

The solution is to turn off mirroring in the Searchable plugin and handle updating indexes manually.

Comment: Thanks, I found a programmatic solution that is less scary than handling indexes myself. Thank you one more time! :)